# Counting number of real and complex entries in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, counting

Say I have a list like this

```
a={-7.61575, 7.5, -6.84206, 6.64598, 5.7654, -5.64823, 4.69842, -4.5, \
-1.86729 + 1.90939 I, -1.86729 - 1.90939 I, 0.905621 + 1.98443 I, 
0.905621 - 1.98443 I, 0.631991 + 1.96227 I, 0.631991 - 1.96227 I, 
0.327801 + 1.9312 I, 0.327801 - 1.9312 I}
```

How do I define a function that counts the number of real and complex entries 0n this list?

Comment: Not sure what format you want, but you might start with CountsBy[a,Head]

Comment: Try: Count[a, _Real] and Count[a, _Complex]

Comment: Is `1. + 0. I` a complex or real number for you?

Comment: `{Head@#[[1]], #[[2]]} & /@ Tally[a, Head[#1] === Head[#2] &]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that in Mathematica, `0` (the exact integer) and `0.` (the floating-point zero) are equal: `0==0.` returns `True`. We can use this trick to split the numbers into those with zero imaginary part ($\mathbb{R}$) and those with non-zero imaginary part ($\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$):

```
a = {1., 1. I, 1. + 0. I};
CountsBy[a, Im[#] == 0 &]
(*    <|True -> 2, False -> 1|>    *)
```

We thus have two real numbers (`True`) and one truly complex one (`False`). This result differs from that obtained by looking at the `Head` of the list entries: `CountsBy[a, Head]` returns `<|Real -> 1, Complex -> 2|>`, which seems wrong.

For the paranoid, a more general formulation uses [`PossibleZeroQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PossibleZeroQ.html) to check for zero-ness of the imaginary part:

```
CountsBy[a, PossibleZeroQ@*Im]
(*    <|True -> 2, False -> 1|>    *)
```

Answer (score 7):

```
Counts[Head /@ a]
```

> <|Real -> 8, Complex -> 8|>

or

```
Length@Cases[a, #] & /@ {_Real, _Complex}
```

> {8, 8}

Answer (score 3):

Using `GroupBy`:

```
MapAt[Length, GroupBy[a, Head], Outer[List, Range[2]]]
(*<|Real -> 8, Complex -> 8|>*)
```

Or, as pointed out, @Lukas Lang:

```
GroupBy[list, Head, Length]
(**<|Real -> 8, Complex -> 8|>**)
```

Comment: You can also use the third argument of `GroupBy` to do the counting for you: `GroupBy[a, Head, Length]`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that important detail, @Lukas Lang! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
list = 
  {-7.61575, 7.5, -6.84206, 6.64598, 5.7654, -5.64823, 
   4.69842, -4.5, -1.86729 + 1.90939 I, -1.86729 - 1.90939 I, 
   0.905621 + 1.98443 I, 0.905621 - 1.98443 I, 0.631991 + 1.96227 I, 
   0.631991 - 1.96227 I, 0.327801 + 1.9312 I, 0.327801 - 1.9312 I};
```

```
Tally[Head /@ list]
```

> {{Real, 8}, {Complex, 8}}

```
{#, Count[list, Blank[#]]} & /@ {Real, Complex}
```

> {{Real, 8}, {Complex, 8}}